# Update audit database name in triggers and views of main database?

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, triggers, reference

I have a a system with two databases, main database and audit database. A lot of the triggers and table views in the main database and audit database are referencing from one database to the other. No I needed to change both databases names but unfortunately they failed to work because they still have the old names in the code.

Is there a code to search and replace the old name used for referencing or in dependence?

Thank you,

Comment: What code? Are you talking about having the database name in stored procedures, views and functions in sql or are you talking about in your application code? We can help but you need to provide some more details.

Comment: Sorry for lack of information... I am talking about the SQL code

Answer (score 0):

You will have to manually fix the references but you can leverage some sql to find the offending objects.

```
select OBJECT_NAME(id) as ObjectName
    , text as ObjectCode
from sys.syscomments
where text like '%YourReplacedDatabaseName%'
```

That will give you a list of functions, procedures, views etc that have the old database name in the code. You will however have to recompile each object after you have updated the code. You could probably utilize some dynamic sql around this to do it for you but I would be nervous about changes on that scale automatically.